# How to create a method that adds a listener and allows adding JAVA code

Tags: java

I've been trying to make an event system for several days now but I can't find a way to do the following.

I can't find a way to make the event interactable from a method, I mean this:

```
    api.addEventListener (event -> {
        CODE
    );
```

The operation is simple, I would like that when the event is fired to the listeners in that method, I could add my code.

I am relatively new to Java and still struggle with this kind of thing.

I currently have these 5 classes:

This interface corresponds to the Listener, the one that will receive the event.

```
    public interface UserCreateMessageListener extends GloballyAttachableListener {
        void fire ();
    }
```

Implementation of the above.

```
    public class UserCreateMessageListenerImpl implements UserCreateMessageListener {
        @Override
        public void fire () {
            //CODE
        }
    }
```

This interface will contain the methods to add listeners and receive the event by adding code (which I intend to look for in the example above)

```
    public interface GloballyAttachableListener {
        default void addUserCreateMessageEvent (UserCreateMessageListener listener) {
            // I add the listeners to my listener initializer
        }
    }
```

This class fires events to declared listeners.

```
    public class Initializer extends ListenerAdapter {
        private static List <UserCreateMessageListener> listeners = new ArrayList <UserCreateMessageListener> ();
    
        public static void addListener (UserCreateMessageListener toAdd) {
            listeners.add (toAdd);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived (MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        for (UserCreateMessageListener e: listeners) {
            e.fire ();
        }
    }
```

This class is the class from which I intend to get information and events.

```
    public interface Api extends GloballyAttachableListener {
    
        default String getPrefix () {
            return ConfigAccessor.getPrefix ();
        }
    
        default long getId () {
            return ConfigAccessor.getId ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please state more clearly what your problem is.  I don't think "I can't find a way to make the event interactable from a method" is clear enough.  I understand the general approach you're  presenting, and it seems sound.  I don't understand what the actual problem is.  Can you please explain it more fully?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Are you asking how you can implement the callback method (`fire` in your example) as a method on some class as opposed to an explicit listener class?

Comment: @stridecolossus yes, that is what I meant. Since I don't know very well what it's called, I didn't know how to name it. 

I don't know how to code
`api.addEvent ... (event -> {
});`

Comment: I see one minor problem that may have nothing to do with your question.  The definition of `GloballyAttachableListener` refers to the `UserCreateMessageListener` class internally, but `UserCreateMessageListener` is a subclass of `GloballyAttachableListener`. You don't generally want a superclass to know anything about one of its subclasses.

Comment: @Steve The problem is that I don't know how to get to the point of `api.addEventListener (event -> {
         CODE
     );`
It's what I need to handle events.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that use template classes for object-specific handling.

ListenerAdapter:

```java
public class ListenerAdapter<T> {
    private final List<EventListener<T>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addEventListener(EventListener<T> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeEventListener(EventListener<T> listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void fire(T item) {
        listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.consume(item));
    }
}
```

EventListener:

```java
public interface EventListener<T> {
    void consume(T item);
}
```

Simple test:

```java
public class User {
    private String name;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListenerAdapter<User> listenerAdapter = new ListenerAdapter<>();
        listenerAdapter.addEventListener(item -> System.out.println(item.getName()));
        listenerAdapter.fire(new User("john"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object with a method that matches the signature of your listener (i.e. in this case `void` return type and no parameters):

```java
class Thing {
    void whatever();
}
```

You can use a *method reference* to refer to it:

```java
Thing thing = new Thing();
initializer.addListener(thing::whatever);
```

You can also specify your listener as a *functional interface*:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface UserCreateMessageListener ... {
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Thing` implement the receiver interface involved, `UserCreateMessageListener` in this case?

Comment: Thing has to be the received event, I will investigate, but I don't know if it is exactly what I put as an example.

Comment: @Steve The method reference is a lambda that implicitly implements the listener.  i.e. you could do `UserCreateMessageListener listener = thing::whatever` and then add that.

Comment: @stridecolossus - Ah, ok.  I haven't done much with lambdas and functional interfaces yet.  I doubt that the OP has either.  I worry that bringing such advanced concepts into this discussion might not benefit the OP or future beginners.

Comment: @Steve Fair point, it seemed to me that method references was what the OP was aiming at.  But agreed it might just be adding more confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful.  I fixed up your code to work as I think you want it to, including adding sample code that exercises all of your interfaces and classes.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface GloballyAttachableListener {

    // COMMENT: This method doesn't make sense to me.  The class doesn't know what class to
    // register with.  It doesn't need the current parameter, as that is the same as "this".
    // So you could pass in the class you want to register this listener with, but I think
    // it's better to do that outside the listener itself.

//    default void addUserCreateMessageEvent (UserCreateMessageListener listener) {
//        // I add the listeners to my listener initializer
//    }
}

class MessageReceivedEvent {
    MessageReceivedEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    private String message;
}

// COMMENT: I assume you want to pass the event to the listeners
interface UserCreateMessageListener extends GloballyAttachableListener {
    void fire (MessageReceivedEvent event);
}

// COMMENT: I think you want this to be an interface, not a class
interface ListenerAdapter {
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event);
}

class Initializer implements ListenerAdapter {

    // COMMENT: Because you're extending a class and overriding a method, I don't think any of this
    // can be static.  You'd want it either all static or none static, as the "listeners" list has to
    // match up with the two methods.

    private List<UserCreateMessageListener> listeners = new ArrayList<UserCreateMessageListener>();

    public void addListener(UserCreateMessageListener toAdd) {
        listeners.add(toAdd);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        for (UserCreateMessageListener e : listeners) {
            e.fire(event);
        }
    }
}

class UserCreateMessageListenerImpl implements UserCreateMessageListener {
    @Override
    public void fire (MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getMessage());
    }
}

// Here's what I think is the crux of your question, which is how to use all this stuff.  In practice,
// you'll probably have the registration of the listener and the call to publish an event in different
// places in your code, but I don't think I have to demonstrate that./

class Test {

    Initializer initializer;

    Test() {
         initializer = new Initializer();
    }

    void doit() {
        UserCreateMessageListenerImpl listener = new UserCreateMessageListenerImpl();
        initializer.addListener(listener);

        // ....

        // This would be in a different place in your real code
        initializer.onMessageReceived(new MessageReceivedEvent("Some message blah blah blah"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.doit();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Some message blah blah blah
```