# Java event system/observer pattern

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I have looked at many implementations of the observer pattern in Java, and none of them seem to function precisely how I would like.

In programming languages I am familiar with, it is possible to create an event object that can be 'connected' to by a listener, and 'fired' by the observable. See the pseudocode below for an example.

```
class MyObservable {
  
  public Event myEvent1
  public Event myEvent2


  public fireEvent1() {
    myEvent1:Fire()
  }

  public fireEvent2() {
    myEvent2:Fire()
  }
}
```

```
class MainClass {

  private onMyEvent1() {
    print("my event 1 fired")
  }

  private onMyEvent2() {
    print("my event 2 fired")
  }

  public MainClass() {
      myObservable = new MyObservable()

      // Pass in the function that i want to be called
      // when myEvent1 is fired.
      myObservable.myEvent1.Connect(onMyEvent1)

      // Pass in the function that i want to be called
      // when myEvent2 is fired.
      myObservable.myEvent1.Connect(onMyEvent2)
  } 

}
```

All the implementations I have seen in Java would require me to create a separate interface for each event. This seems very laborious. I also have classes that listen to many events which means my listeners implement up to 10 interfaces, which doesn't seem right to me. Is there really no better/quicker way of doing the observer pattern in Java?

The minimum equivalent code in Java from the above pseudocode, or just links to good implementations of the observer pattern in Java will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that a variable number of parameters can be passed into the fire() method (not in the pseudocode implementation sorry!).

For example in myEvent1.fire(5,3), the numbers 5 and 3 can be used in fireEvent1(int num1, int num2)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65310654/13106495

Comment: There's the `Observable` class in Java that might help.  Here's [one example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-observable-class-java/)

Comment: You might also Google AspectJ - then you can use annotations and never have to worry about calling the code from the observable object at all.  Be advised, though, this approach is like hitting a tree stump with an atom bomb.

Comment: You might be able to save some work and use the Proxy class, but you don't go into your requirements a lot here.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

`PropertyChangeSupport` would be an option. There are multiple event systems already present, and also libraries which add such functionality (e.g. via annotations, so you don't have to write the boiler code yourself). `EventListenerList` would be another existing system - check `AbstractTableModel` for a usage example.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class Model {
  private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
  private String                field1  = "";

  public void setField1(String newValue) {
    String oldValue = this.field1;
    this.field1 = newValue;
    support.firePropertyChange("field1", oldValue, newValue);
  }

  public void addField1Listener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    support.addPropertyChangeListener("field1", listener);
  }

  public void removeField1Listener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    support.removePropertyChangeListener("field1", listener);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model model = new Model();
    model.addField1Listener(e -> System.out.println("field1 changed to: " + model.field1));
    model.setField1("new");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a direct translation of your pseudocode (note, the code is not thread-safe), and would reasonably do the job you seem to want. To be clear, this is not necessarily the best solution, and various Java frameworks provide different methods of defining and handling events.

```java
public class Event {
  private final List<Runnable> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

  public void connect(Runnable handler) {
    handlers.add(handler);
  }

  public void fire() {
    for (Runnable handler : new ArrayList<>(handlers)) {
      handler.run();
    }
  }
}
```

`Event` uses the basic `Runnable` interface for actions to execute when the event is fired.

```java
class MyObservable {
  
  public Event myEvent1
  public Event myEvent2

  public fireEvent1() {
    myEvent1.fire()
  }

  public fireEvent2() {
    myEvent2.fire()
  }
}
```

```java
class MainClass {

  private onMyEvent1() {
    print("my event 1 fired")
  }

  private onMyEvent2() {
    print("my event 2 fired")
  }

  public MainClass() {
      myObservable = new MyObservable()

      myObservable.myEvent1.connect(this::onMyEvent1)

      myObservable.myEvent1.connect(this::onMyEvent2)
  } 
}
```

`Main` uses method reference to create `Runnable` implementations for its methods to register with `Event`.

Comment: Totally my fault, but I forgot to write that a variable number of parameters can be passed into fire(). For example in myEvent1.fire(5,3), the numbers 5 and 3 can be used in fireEvent1(int num1, int num2).

Comment: @Sid Yes, that complicates matters significantly, and no there is no one-size-fits-all solution for that in Java.